# Trying to compile LzmaUtil.c from LZMA SDK

Tags: c, lzma

I wish to use LZMA natively in my own C util. I've downloaded LZMA SDK from http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html (version 9.12 beta) - but I simply fail to compile their LzmaUtil.

This is what I've tried, using MinGW:

```
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -D_7ZIP_ST LzmaUtil.c ../../Alloc.c ../../LzFind.c ../../LzmaDec.c ../../LzmaEnc.c ../../7zFile.c ../../7zStream.c -o lzma.exe
LzmaUtil.c: In function `Decode2':
LzmaUtil.c:95: warning: suggest parentheses around && within ||
```

When I try to use lzma: "lzma.exe e inputfile outputfile" - Nothing happens. (simply returns without printing or creating the outputfile)

Anybody can help, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-c` option creates an object file, not an executable. Remove the `-c` and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate... now I can waste my time trying to figure out what's going on inside :)